# Image preload jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm looking for the best way to preload images with jQuery.

I tried using this code but it doesn't seem to work:

```
    function preload(arrayOfImages) {
        $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
            $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
            // Alternatively you could use:
            // (new Image()).src = this;
        });
    }

    // Usage:

    preload([
        'img/preload.jpg'
    ]);
```

This is my markup:

```
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/lookbook_item1.jpg" alt="lookbook_item1" width="187" height="259">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/lookbook_item1.jpg" alt="lookbook_item1" width="187" height="259">
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/lookbook_item2.jpg" alt="lookbook_item2" width="383" height="259">
                </div>
```

I don't want to use plugins, just a small script that can do a fadeIn or something similar.

Comment: The code you posted does not work because you are not preloading the images you have on the page

Comment: @mplungjan I misunderstood the question and deleted my answer immediately. You're right, the images will load themselves and show up when loaded completely. I think OP wants to pre-load some images that are not part of the DOM, then fade them in.

Comment: @fxg Do you want to pre-load the images that are not part of your page and, after loading them, you want to put them in the page and fade in?

Comment: I want to make something similar to this: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html without using a plugin. My images are part of the page, not loaded after :)

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way:

```
$.each( arrayOfImages, function( i, src ) {
  var img = new Image()
  img.src = src;
  img.load = function() {
    $("img[src=" + src + "]").fadeIn();
  };
});
```

Comment: @fxg you need to put this inside your `preload` function. This is just a basic example to fill in your own code, not a full runnable code.

Comment: I am sure it is img.onload and you need to define the onload before the src is changed.

Comment: ok I have put it inside the preload function. but now it just doesn't do anything. The image loads by parts as always.. no fadeIn

Comment: You have to hide the images first.

Comment: Apparently not or your css isn't working... If the image appear, then they're not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

HTML

```
<div class="item">
  <img src="placeholder.gif" data-src="img/lookbook_item1.jpg" alt="lookbook_item1" width="187" height="259">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="placeholder.gif" data-src="img/lookbook_item2.jpg" alt="lookbook_item1" width="187" height="259">
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="placeholder.gif" data-src="img/lookbook_item3.jpg" alt="lookbook_item1" width="187" height="259">
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {    
    var urls = $('.item img').each(function () {
       var img = new Image();
       var src = $(this).data("src");
       img.onload = function () {
          $("img[data-src=" + src + "]").attr("src",src).fadeIn();
       };
       img.src = src;
    });
 });
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution without altering the html markup. Thank you anyway!

Comment: Then you just need to add the urls from your page to the preload array